# Getting project list from jira in php application, using jira rest api

Tags: php, jira-rest-api

I am working on a custom PHP application in which I need to print list of projects from Jira using the Jira REST API. I am using following code:

```
$response = @file_get_contents("https://example.atlassian.net/jira/rest/api/latest/project?expand");
if($response === false)
{
    echo "Error";
}
print_r($response);
```

But it is showing error because response is false. I have searched on web but did not get any suitable answer.

I have used login name and password in following way:

```
$response = @file_get_contents("https://example.atlassian.net/jira/rest/api/latest/project?expand&os_username=$user&os_password=$pass");
```

But it still gives error.

Comment: Is this Jira installation public? I'm missing some user/password combination in the url for basic http auth.

Comment: I have added code that uses login info.

Comment: please remove the "@" sign and tell us the exact error message.

Comment: I have removed "@", but still error. How can I get error details? It simply set $response to false.

Comment: what's the output if you request the same URL via. curl/wget or a browser?

Comment: I have tried in browser. It simply says: "Oops, you've found a dead link."

I am using email address as login id. Do we need to raw encode that?

Comment: yes please try to encode the email address

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78877/discussion-between-gries-and-vishal-suri).